# .htaccess - Allow direct access to multiple, specific files while blocking the rest

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been doing research around the forum and Google but all the resources pointed out to block all file but one file. I need to allow more than one file for direct access. Please take a look at the current .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The above code will block all but `/index.php`. How will I allow more files for direct access, say, `/static_app.php`?